# Cosmos DB: How i can rollback multiple containers?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, .net-7.0

I'm a newbie with Azure Cosmos DB. My project uses C# 11/Net 7.0.

Today, I try to execute multiple operations in a time:

- Insert entity A.
- Update entity B.
- Delete entity C.
  Finally,I want to "Rollback" all changes if there are any errors.

I can't use a transaction because Azure Cosmos Db only supports a transaction per a container.

How i can do it?
I'm really sorry because my English is bad.
Thank all!

Comment: Are the entities in different containers?

Comment: Slight clarification: Transactions are supported within a *partition* within a container. If your updates are across partitions (or containers), you would need to come up with your own solution. Hint: check out the *compensating transaction* pattern as a starting place.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm trying to execute many transactions using Task. After that, whether there are any failed transactions? I will deal with all the transactions (one-by-one) that have been applied using previous state through APIs.
However, I feel this solution so bad.

Comment: "*However, I feel this solution [is] so bad*" - I don't understand what you mean here, but... Cosmos DB does not have the same type of transactions as, say, SQL Server, where you can do a bunch of things across a bunch of tables, and rollback or commit. You can do that within a single partition of a single container. There are well-known patterns to deal with rollback, as I already shared with you. I would suggest either looking at those, or looking more carefully whether you *really* need to execute everything in a transaction (vs, say, a message based approach or other alternative ways)